# How to generate regex patterns in python using re.compile

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to create a python code that will be able to extract the information from strings such as the one below, using regular expressions.

date=2019-10-26 time=17:59:00 logid="0000000020" type="traffic" subtype="forward" level="notice" vd="root" eventtime=1572127141 srcip=192.168.6.15 srcname="TR" srcport=522 srcintf="port1" srcintfrole="lan" dstip=172.217.15.194 dstport=43 dstintf="wan2" dstintfrole="wan" poluuid="feb1fa32-d08b-51e7-071f-19e3b5d2213c" sessionid=195421734 proto=6 action="accept" policyid=4 policytype="policy" service="HTTPS" dstcountry="United States" srccountry="Reserved" trandisp="snat" transip=168.168.140.247 transport=294 appid=537 app="Google.Ads" appcat="General.Interest" apprisk="elevated" applist="Seniors" appact="detected" duration=719 sentbyte=2691 rcvdbyte=2856 sentpkt=19 rcvdpkt=25 shapingpolicyid=1 sentdelta=449 rcvddelta=460 devtype="Linux" devcategory="Linux" mastersrcmac="fa:cc:4e:a3:56:2d" srcmac="fa:cc:4e:a3:56:2d" srcserver=0

I found someone's code on github and he uses the lines below to extract the information, however, his code doesn't extract all of the fields I require, most notably srcip=192.168.1.105

I don't want to post the guy's entire code as it's not mine. However, if it is required I can.

I am hoping all the fields will be extracted from the jumble of information so I can save them as a .csv file.

Comment: Can you add the code or pattern that you tried to the question and specify what you expect to match? Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `\w+=([^\s"]+|"[^"]*")` matches

- The field name (at least one word character), then
- An `=` sign, then
- Either:

  - An unquoted field value (at least one character, excluding whitespace and quotes), or
  - A quoted field value (`"`, then any number of non-quotes, then `"`).

By adding parentheses around the parts of the regex which match field name, and the unquoted and quoted values, we can extract the relevant parts and put them into a dictionary using a comprehension, using the `findall` method:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+)=(([^\s"]+)|"([^"]*)")')
def parse_fields(text):
    return {
        name: (value or quoted_value)
        for name,_,value,quoted_value in pattern.findall(text)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I used this line to solve the issue : pattern = re.compile(
    '(\w+)(?:=)(?:([^\s,""]+|"(?:\\.|[^""])*"))|(\w+)=(?:([\w\-\.:\=]+))')

Answer (score 0):

Same as kaya3, but I don't keep the quotes

```
s = '''date=2019-10-26 time=17:59:00 logid="0000000020" type="traffic"
subtype="forward" level="notice" vd="root" eventtime=1572127141
srcip=192.168.6.15 srcname="TR" srcport=522 srcintf="port1" srcintfrole="lan"
dstip=172.217.15.194 dstport=43 dstintf="wan2" dstintfrole="wan"
poluuid="feb1fa32-d08b-51e7-071f-19e3b5d2213c" sessionid=195421734 proto=6
action="accept" policyid=4 policytype="policy" service="HTTPS"
dstcountry="United States" srccountry="Reserved" trandisp="snat"
transip=168.168.140.247 transport=294 appid=537 app="Google.Ads"
appcat="General.Interest" apprisk="elevated" applist="Seniors"
appact="detected" duration=719 sentbyte=2691 rcvdbyte=2856 sentpkt=19
rcvdpkt=25 shapingpolicyid=1 sentdelta=449 rcvddelta=460 devtype="Linux"
devcategory="Linux" mastersrcmac="fa:cc:4e:a3:56:2d" srcmac="fa:cc:4e:a3:56:2d"
srcserver=0'''

import re

matches = re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)=(?:"([^"]+)"|(\S+))', s)

d = {
    name: quoted or unquoted
    for name, quoted, unquoted in matches
}
```